# Iframe и SQL-запрос

Tags: php

Использую скрипт через iframe, и в нем использую такой запрос:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `logs` VALUES('LAST_INSER_ID()', '1', '2', '3');");
```

Все без ошибок проходит, но запись не добавляет... сразу несколько пояснений:

1. если запустить этот запрос без iframe - работает
2. если вместо `LAST_INSER_ID()` (пробовал и `LAST_INSERT_ID()`) какое-то число, то проходит запрос
3. подключение к БД офк имеется
4. вывод сделал, что через `iframe` не работает `LAST_INSER_ID()`, как его
       можно обойти или подкоректировать запрос

Кто разбирается, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

LAST_INSER_ID() вообще не существует. Нужно использовать LAST_INSERT_ID(), и ошибки обрабатывать при отладке:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `logs` VALUES('LAST_INSERT_ID()', '1', '2', '3');") or die (mysql_error());
```